How to bind a socket to a multicast UDP port on Windows-10 with python?
This is a python-related programming question that maybe cannot be answered at all. Maybe there is no solution.
But here is the setup: I am using Windows-10 on a hp laptop and a device in a local network sends out UDP packages for destination 239.0.0.4 and port 45004 (As can be confirmed via wireshark). That device is connected to a USB Ethernet connector named Ethernet with a static IP address 192.168.200.5 and subnetmask 255.255.255.0.

I am trying the following python (3.10.11) code to create a socket in order to read the packages from that device (the exact same python code works without any issues on Ubuntu on the same laptop and the same device):
import socket

mcast_grp = "239.0.0.3"
port = 45004
adaptor = "192.168.200.5"
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((mcast_grp, port))  # FAILING LINE
mreq = struct.pack("4s4s", socket.inet_aton(mcast_grp), socket.inet_aton(adaptor))
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

But that python code fails on the indicated line with the error
    sock.bind((mcast_grp, port))
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

Is there ANY way to rewrite this python code so it also works on windows?

On Windows, you can't bind a socket to a multicast group IP, only to a local interface IP. In the case of multicast, you should bind() to the INADDR_ANY wildcard, and then use IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP to subscribe the desired interface IP to the multicast group to indicate that you want to receive multicast packets on that interface.

Why does it work under Linux that way? Shouldn't the socket library made be that way so it works on both OS the same way? Why this profound difference?

@Alex Windows is not Linux. Different platforms are free to do things their own way.

But the socket module is supposed to do the same, correct? Why does this module behave totally DIFFERENTLY on two OS platforms? THAT was my question.

You would have to ask Microsoft WHY they do things differently (and they do a lot of things differently). The fact is, they ARE different, so you just have to code around it.

Remy, that was not my question here. Yes, microsoft does things differently than it is done in Linux. Yes I agree. Yes, that is a known fact. And yes, you have to code around it. So when I would create a module for python I would consider these differences to make sure the API works the same under windows and Linux. I would code that module around the differences between microsoft and linux. But the question is: Why did the creators of the socketmodule for python not code around this so the API works the same for users under windows and Linux? That was my question here ...

@Alex Ask the Python authors. WHY questions that ask for speculation or opinions are not a good fit for StackOverflow. Only the people who designed the APIs know WHY they designed it the way they did. The Python socket documentation does state it just calls the underlying BSD socket API and thus some functionality is platform-specific. This is one of those cases, since Multicast APIs are not uniform across platforms.

To capture the data from an ethernet device using python on Windows-10 it is possible to use the third-party module pyshark. That allows to capture and select the requested packets from the device.
Here is an example code how to do that:
import pyshark
    
def capture_ethernet_traffic(interface, destination_ip):
    capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface=interface)
    for packet in capture.sniff_continuously():
        # Select UDP packets directed to a certain IP address
        if "IP" in packet "UDP" in packet and packet.ip.dst == destination_ip:                   
            # Extract the data as bytes
            captured_data = bytearray.fromhex(packet.data.data)
            print(captured_data)

            # process that data as required
            ...

interface = "Ethernet 7"  # Replace with your interface name
destination_ip = "239.0.0.3"
capture_ethernet_traffic(interface, destination_ip)

Works like a charm...

I have a question about which filters I can use in Pyshark to filter for login errors. I have found the FTP case, the HTTP case, and the SMB case. Would be OK if I post a question in StackOveflow. Would it be appropriate? I see that that you are a top contributor. May you help me?
